# jQuery - function followed by if condition in the same event

Tags: jquery, html, css

So this is what I want to do;

Click on one of the buttons to add the class 'clicked'

Click on the same button again to bring up the alert.

Currently the alert comes up on the same click.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/d68wsa32/

HTML

```
<div class="button">
button click here
</div>
<div class="button">
button click here
</div>
<div class="button">
button click here
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.button').each(function(){

$(this).on('click',function(){

    $(this).addClass('clicked');

    if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){    
        alert('bingo');
    };

});

});
```

CSS

```
.button{
background-color:red;
color:white;
padding:1em;
margin:5px;
text-align:center;
}

.clicked{
background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Because you add the class than check! It is like grabbing a piece of paper and than checking if you have paper in your hand. It should be there since you just picked it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your code around a bit:

```
  if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){    
        alert('bingo');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have
`$(this).addClass('clicked');`
after your if statement. Right now you are adding the class and then checking for the class.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the test before doing the alert, and add the class if it's not already there:

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click',function(){

        if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){    
            alert('bingo');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }

    });
});
```

But there's no reason at all for that `each` loop. Instead:

```
$(".button").on('click',function(){

    if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){    
        alert('bingo');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }

});
```

It will still work per-button, because within the `click` event handler, `this` will refer only to the element that was clicked.

If you want it to toggle, you'd also use `removeClass` after the `alert`, but I wasn't sure you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem best:
Simply place `$(this).addClass('clicked');` after your `if` statement. Like so...

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){    
    alert('bingo');
};

$(this).addClass('clicked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it separately:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button:not(.clicked)", function () {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
$(document).on("click", ".button.clicked", function () {
    alert("bingo");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work : first look if it has the class, else add it.

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){    
            alert('bingo');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**`each()`** is unnecessary here.

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('clicked') )
        alert('bingo');
    else
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```